# WSO2 UES user-engagement-serve

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

Can a gadget created in WSO2 BAM, be viewed in WSO2 UES dashboard?

The gadget can be viewed in BAM Gadget Server, but does not display data in a UES Dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Well, These are two different server instances and there is no tool to link those gadget between two server on a single click, however you can achieve this pragmatically as below.

1. Create jaggary file (data access file to read data set from DB) in BAM server to read the data from BAM RDBMS.
2. Create gadget in UES and use BAM server data file to get your data for the gadget. For this you need to edit the chart draw code in UES to read data from BAM jaggary file.

For this you need to do jaggary coding ( http://jaggeryjs.org/  )

NOTE:  Also in future, UES is going to be bundled with BAM, So when you have BAM , you have UES within it.  Release date not available as of now but it will be in one of next major version release.